# Panda.str.contains with ascii codec encode error

Tags: python, string, unicode, encoding, utf-8

I am getting the classic codex encoding error:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 11-12: ordinal not in range(128)
```

from the following code:

```
def compare_handles(handle):
    new_df = df[df['Creation Specifications'].astype(str).str.contains(handle)]
```

the initial dataframe comes from an excel file, where the column contains both strings, special chars, and hyperlinks. I was having initial problems with this line until i added astype(str). However, further down in the code it threw the this error.

My question is how do i encode to a better codex when I am having to use the str.contains function? Given the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/unicode.html#the-unicode-type) on the basics of this issue, the key is to drop the str part and add encode. However, because I am using the pandas function contains, its not really possible to "just drop the str".

I could create create a mapping, but I was wondering if there is a cleaner answer.

Note: i did try using encode utf-8 and latin in every possible position in the above code line.

Answer (score 1):

You can double str a pandas line.

```
new_df = complete_df[complete_df['Creation Specifications'].str.encode('utf-8', errors='ignore').str.contains(handle)]
```